# SQL display ID of any customer who has never placed an order, using set-based operations only

Tags: sql, oracle, set-based

Couldn't find anything on this, using set-based operations.
Not sure if I'm on the right track, but I have 2 guesses on how to do this, but I'm not sure if I'm even close, or if MINUS is the right set-based operation to use:

```
SELECT customerid
FROM customer
MINUS
SELECT orderid
FROM custorder
WHERE custorder IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT customerid
FROM customer
MINUS
SELECT orderid
FROM custorder;
```

Suggestions on how to improve or what to change? Any help is appreciated. 
Could someone also possibly explain when to use UNION, UNION ALL, or INTERSECT on a similar sample like this?

Also, I'm not sure if I need these in 2 different tables or not. In this database, 2 of these tables are CUSTOMER (has customerid) and CUSTORDER (has customerid and orderid). Here's a screenshot of the table values if you wanted to see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvbB.jpg

***NOTE: I HAVE TO USE SET-BASED OPERATIONS ONLY FOR FULL CREDIT***

Answer (score 1):

probably more like

```
select customerid 
from customer
MINUS
select customerid
from custorder;
```

you need to MINUS off the same type of values from the set

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where not exists (select 1
                  from custorder co
                  where co.customerid = c.customerid
                 );
```

You can do something similar with `not in` and `left join`/`where`.

The set-based approach is:

```
SELECT customerid
FROM customer
MINUS
SELECT customerid
FROM custorder;
```

The advantage of the first method is that you can select additional columns from `customer`.